# Should I have one table for language and one for category?

Tags: .net, database, database-design

I am doing a simple application in asp.net mvc. The user can add articles that belong to various categories and languages. The user should also be able to add and remove categories and languages. What I can come up with, I have a table "articles" but because each article can have various categories and languages, I need to have different tables for that?

Here's how I imagine it (tables)

```
**articles**
articlesID | categoriesID | languagesID | Title | Price

**categories**
categoriesID | Name

**languages**
languagesID | Name
```

I think (as a beginner). Do I need two tables (categories and languages) with just ID and name?

Edit
It has come up that it should be possible to create sub-categories and maybe even deeper category -> subcategory -> subcategory. I am thinking about creating a new table subcategory but if the user wants to add a subsubcategory I have to add another table.

Answer (score 1):

If an article can belong to more then one category, and naturally, categories can have multiple articles, then you need to connect them using another table to create a `many to many` relationship.
Same goes for languages, however, you would probably want the different translations of the article to have the same Id.
I suggest something like this:

```sql
TblArticles
(
    Article_Id int,
    Article_Title nvarchar(300), -- or whatever length that works for you
    Article_Body nvarchar(max),
    -- any other article data such as create date, number of reads, etc'.
)

TblCategories
(
     Category_Id int,
     Category_Name nvarchar(20)
)

TblLanguages
(
     Language_Id int,
     Language_Name nvarchar(20)
     -- perhaps Language_NativeName as well
)

TblArticleToCategory
(
    ArticleToCategory_Article_Id int, -- Foreign key to TblArticles
    ArticleToCategory_Category_Id int -- Foreign key to TblCategories
)
```

for the connection to the languages table, I would create a table like this:

```sql
TblTranslatedArticles
(
    TranslatedArticle_Id int,
    TranslatedArticle_Article_Id int, -- Foreign key to TblArticles
    TranslatedArticle_Language_Id int, -- Foreign key to TblLanguages
    TranslatedArticle__Title nvarchar(300), -- or whatever length that works for you
    TranslatedArticle__Body nvarchar(max),
    -- any other article data that needs a translation
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It has come up that it should be possible to create sub-categories and maybe even deeper category -> subsubcategory -> subcategory. How does it work (subcategories) with your solution?

Comment: Basicaly this may be handled inside the category table itself. I'll edit my answer to elaborate on it in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you create tables for your application, be sure to complete the conditions for Database Normalization. The link below is very helpful:
http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php
However, for the Articles table, i would prefer only the first 2 fields, so an Article-Properties Table can come in hand with the following structure:

```
article_id int
categories_id int
```

, the article itself should have a different table:

```
id int
title varchar
price int
```

...
,
the language table:

```
id int
language varchar,
```

and finally, the categories table:

```
id int
categoryName varchar
```

About the language-article relation i think you should consider Zohar's point,of many to many relations,so:

```
Translated_Article_Id int
Original_Article_Id int 
Translated_Language_Id
Translated_Language_Title varchar
```

.
.
.(Here you can add every other field you need)

This way is much more easier to maintain and edit the entered data

Comment: this structure does not allow for many-to-many relationship between articles and categories.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It has come up that it should be possible to create sub-categories and maybe even deeper category -> subsubcategory -> subcategory. How does it work (subcategories) with your solution?

Comment: @Xtreme for each article,, what will be the final result, the category or the subcategory?